# Creating a ticking watch without referencing to the systemclock

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried to build my own clock without referencing to the system clock.

I can write the program in several ways, but it won't work.

Do you have a clue?

```
import time
from tkinter import *
 
# Objekt der Klasse Tk erstellt und Fensterüberschrift
fenster = Tk()          
fenster.wm_title("Uhrzeit")
 
# Uhrzeit wird über ein Label angezeigt und mit pack im fenster gezeigt
uhr = Label(master=fenster,
            font=('Arial',30),
            fg='blue',
            width = 15,
            height = 3)
uhr.pack()
 
zeit = ''
 
# Abfrage der Zeit vom laufenden Computer
# mit config wird das Label neu beschriftet
# mit after wird nach 0,2sek die Funktion tick neu aufgerufen
 
def tick(hour,min):
    global zeit
    if len(str(hour))<2:
        hour=f"0{hour}"
    if len(str(min))<2:
        min=f"0{min}"
    print(hour,min)
    neuezeit = f"{hour}:{min}"
    print(neuezeit,zeit)
    if neuezeit != zeit:
        zeit = neuezeit
        uhr.config(text = zeit)
    neuzeit=tick23(hour,min)
    NeuStd=int(neuzeit[:2])
    NeuMin=int(neuzeit[3:])
    time.sleep(5)
    uhr.after(tick(NeuStd,NeuMin))

def tick23(x,y):
    if int(x)<24:
        if int(y)==59:
            x=str(int(x)+1)
            y=0
        else:
            y=str(int(y)+1)
    else:
        x=0
        y=0         
    if len(str(x))<2:
        x=f"0{x}"
    if len(str(y))<2:
        y=f"0{y}"
    return f"{x}:{y}"     
tick(14,30)
uhr.mainloop() # Programm startet
```

Comment: What doesn't work?  Note that you cannot do `time.sleep` inside a GUI handler.  That will block the entire program.  Note that `uhr.after(tick(NeuStd,NeuMin))` will immediate call `tick (thereby causing an infinite recursion loop)`, and will pass its return value (which is `None`) to `uhr.after`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. I don't know Tkinter so I didn't bother reading the code, but FWIW, just saying that it doesn't work is generally not helpful. Instead, describe *how* it doesn't work, and ask a specific question about that. See [mre] as well as [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask). You can [edit]. Please also translate into English as much as possible so that it's easier for non-German-speakers to understand.

Comment: One thing most developers learn the hard way somewhere at the beginning of their careers: Don't try to implement date and time functions on your own, there's a library for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is closer to what you are trying to do.  Note the use of lambda in the `after` call, which allows the `tick` function to return to be called back later.

Also note that I have this updating every second, so we can see it run.  You can change the "1000" to "60000" to have it done once a minute, but of course the better way would be to use the system clock.  The callbacks aren't as exact as you might hope.

```
import time
from tkinter import *
 
# Objekt der Klasse Tk erstellt und Fensterüberschrift
fenster = Tk()          
fenster.wm_title("Uhrzeit")
 
# Uhrzeit wird über ein Label angezeigt und mit pack im fenster gezeigt
uhr = Label(master=fenster,
            font=('Arial',30),
            fg='blue',
            width = 15,
            height = 3)
uhr.pack()
 
zeit = ''
 
# Abfrage der Zeit vom laufenden Computer
# mit config wird das Label neu beschriftet
# mit after wird nach 0,2sek die Funktion tick neu aufgerufen
 
def tick(hour,min):
    global zeit
    neuezeit = f"{hour:02d}:{min:02d}"
    print(neuezeit,zeit)
    if neuezeit != zeit:
        zeit = neuezeit
        uhr.config(text = zeit)
    min += 1
    if min >= 60:
        min = 0
        hour += 1
        if hour >= 24:
            hour = 0
    uhr.after(1000, tick, hour, min)

tick(14,30)
uhr.mainloop() # Programm startet
```

Comment: FWIW, you don't have to use `lambda`. `after` allows you to provide positional arguments (eg: `uhr.after(1000, tick, hour, min)`)

Comment: Excellent note, I'll make that change.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how works the system clock! There must be also a kind of callback in the system or?

Comment: You would still use `after` to do the callback, but use the system time facilities to fetch the current time instead of trying to track it yourself.  Both `time` and `datetime` provide easy ways to fetch the current time as a sting.